# ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError issue with everything as per the Docs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

Below are my models:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :client_authorization_rules
  has_many :projects, through: :client_authorization_rule

end

class Project < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :client_authorization_rules
  has_many :clients, through: :client_authorization_rule

end

class ClientAuthorizationRule < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :client

  validates_presence_of :project
  validates_presence_of :client

end
```

So, I have followed everything as per the docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

The errors I am getting is when I do something like:

```
p.clients
```

Here "p" is a project. I cannot even access the "clients" method on the project without getting the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :client_authorization_rule in model Project
```

Not sure what I am missing. Thanks. My Rails version is Rails 5.0.6 and ruby 2.2.3. Is this some known issue? I cant find any one with this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> through: :client_authorization_rule

it should be client_authorization_rules

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :client_authorization_rules
  has_many :projects, through: :client_authorization_rules

end

class Project < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :client_authorization_rules
  has_many :clients, through: :client_authorization_rules

end
```

one more thing as a side note when you write `belongs_to :project` in rails 5 it automatically means thats `project_id` is required before save. so there is no sense of  `validates_presence_of :project`

```
class ClientAuthorizationRule < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :project #it means that project_id required is true
  belongs_to :client  #it means that client_id required is true

  #validates_presence_of :project
  #validates_presence_of :client

end
```

Comment: Sheesh okay my bad. Pluralisation is important i guess!

Answer (score 3):

Following

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :client_authorization_rules
  has_many :projects, through: :client_authorization_rule

end

class Project < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :client_authorization_rules
  has_many :clients, through: :client_authorization_rule

end
```

Should be

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord    
  has_many :client_authorization_rules
  has_many :projects, through: :client_authorization_rules    
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord    
  has_many :client_authorization_rules
  has_many :clients, through: :client_authorization_rules    
end
```

Note :- `through: :client_authorization_rule` should be `through: :client_authorization_rules`